# Excel VBA: Compare formulas / formula structure of two cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write a code where I test whether the formula / formula structure in two cells are comparable. The purpose of the code is to check if the formula in one cell has been copied from e.g. the cell to the left or the cell above. Hence, I need to test if the structure of the formula is the same, if absolute cell references are the same and relative cell references change like they would when you copy a cell.

Example:
Let's say Cell B5 in Sheet2 contains the formula "=Sheet1!***B3***+$A$1/10". I would then like to check if cell C5 contains the formula "=Sheet1!***C3***+$A$1/10" and get true/false as the result.

I know it's customary to post the code you are working on here, but I am not sure if it's beneficial or just confusing in this case. I have tried three approaches this far:

1. Trace direct precedents of the original cell (let's say B5 from the example above), offset them and replace them in the formula extracted from B5 and check if the formula is equal to the formula in C5. *Does not work as trace precedents can't handle off-sheet references.*
2. Get all cell references in a formula by using RegExp. Offset these references and replace them in the formula extracted from B5 and test if this formula is equal to C5. This approach will probably work if I am able to finish it, but it'll be an incredibly large and complicated sub with a lot of text handling and a lot of work for something that I suspect there is an easier approach to.
3. Use a "help" sheet where I copy cell B5 to C5 and check if the formula is equal to the original formula in cell C5. It'll work, but takes waaaaay to much time if I want to check a large range/sheet.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I think you have to specificly ask for the properties.
In addition to this, you could run a loop whichs goes from cell to cell and compare single cells. Example: If Sheets("Name").Cells(x,y).Font.Bald = true and Sheets("Name").Cells(a,b).Font.Bald = true then do something or give me "there" a value

Can you maybe give the specific values that you want to compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Debug.Print SameFormula(Range("B8"), Range("C8"))
End Sub

Public Function SameFormula(ByVal rng1 As Range, ByVal rng2 As Range) As Boolean
    If rng1.HasFormula And rng2.HasFormula Then
        SameFormula = rng1.FormulaR1C1 = rng2.FormulaR1C1
    Else
        SameFormula = False
    End If
End Function
```

Where B8 has `=Sheet1!B3+$A$1/10` and C8 has `=Sheet1!C3+$A$1/10` . You can tweak this idea.

Without HasFormula for earlier versions:

```
Public Function SameFormula2(ByVal rng1 As Range, ByVal rng2 As Range) As Boolean
    If Left$(rng1.Formula, 1) = "=" And Left$(rng2.Formula, 1) = "=" Then
        SameFormula2 = rng1.FormulaR1C1 = rng2.FormulaR1C1
    Else
        SameFormula2 = False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: That is absolutely brilliant. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Another Idea;

Compare the Len() of `FormulaR1C1` - this is a good heuristic for finding identical or similar formulae. Here's some code I wrote to change the fill of all the cells in a workbook so similar colours have similar formulas

```vb
Sub showFormulas()
    Dim s As Worksheet
    For Each s In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If s.Visible Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Dim formulas As Range
            Set formulas = s.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                Debug.Print s.Name; " skipped;", Err.Description
            Else
                formulas.Interior.Pattern = XlPattern.xlPatternGray8
                Dim r As Range
                For Each r In formulas
                    r.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 255) * 0.85 + 0.15 * (Log(Len(r.FormulaR1C1) / 10)) * RGB(0, 255, 0)
                Next r
            End If
            Err.Clear
        End If
    Next s
End Sub
```

the important line is this:

```vb
r.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 255) * 0.85 + 0.15 * (Log(Len(r.FormulaR1C1) / 10)) * RGB(0, 255, 0)
```

Which mixes 2 colours: Magenta `RGB(255, 0, 255)` and Green `RGB(0, 255, 0)` where more green is added the longer the formula is. Green has the most sensitive colour reception in the human eye. I use `Log` since I want the same step in colour when the fomula length doubles, not when I add a fixed number of characters.

Result is something like this to differentiate different formulas by colour:

---

#### Before

[image]

---

#### After

[image]